# Javascript ouputs undefined, the code seems to be alright

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have an codeigniter based website. I am trying to output user information to print out a shipping label for them. Everything works okay however the information that is displayed in the new pop out window is not in the right format and one of the parameters is coming up as undefined. The code I am using is below:

from admin_controller.php

---

```
public function address(){
        $data['Address']=$this->input->get("Address");
        $data['firstname']=$this->input->get("firstname");
        $data['lastname']=$this->input->get("lastname"); 
        $data['address1']=$this->input->get("address1");
        $data['address2']=$this->input->get("address2");
        $data['suburb']=$this->input->get("suburb");
        $data['state']=$this->input->get("state");
        $data['postcode']=$this->input->get("postcode");
        $data['mobile']=$this->input->get("mobile");
        $this->load->view('admin/address',$data);
    }
```

---

Code related to the button itself

---

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" onClick="Address('<?php echo $order->firstname ?>','<?php echo $order->lastname ?>','<?php echo $order->address1 ?>','<?php echo $order->address2 ?>','<?php echo $order->suburb ?>','<?php echo $order->state ?>','<?php echo $order->postcode ?>','<?php echo $order->mobile ?>')"> Label </a>
```

---

The Script

---

```
<script>
    function Address(val,firstname,lastname,address1,address2,suburb,state,postcode,mobile){
       window.open("<?php echo base_url();?>admin_controller/address?Address="+val+"&firstname="+firstname+"&lastname="+lastname+"&address1="+address1+"&address2="+address2+"&suburb="+suburb+"&state="+state+"&postcode="+postcode+"&mobile="+mobile+"",null,"width=800,height=400,left=100,top=100");
    }

</script>
```

---

Comment: 'function Address(val, '
where  you are not sending 'val' param from button click
add param onClick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing a value for parameter `val` to your Javascript function.

```
onClick="Address('<?php echo $order->firstname ?>'
```

should be something like:

```
onClick="Address('theValue', '<?php echo $order->firstname ?>'
```

Comment: Just a question, If I remove the parameter    val , the button stops working.

Comment: @JaydenJalvi Your function has 9 parameters but you are passing only 8 values. So there's one value missing.

Comment: @JaydenJalvi If you remove parameter `val` you also have to remove the `Address="+val+"` in your code.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the issue! I love StackOverflow!